# ggplot2 | geom_bar and position = "identity"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am an absolute beginner, and I have recently started using excellent package ggplot. I have a question about using position = "identity" with bar chart. I searched through the internet and found this: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_tile.html However, they are not in relation to geom_bar()

A) First graph: (which works well)

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(color, fill = cut)) +
geom_bar()
```

This plots frequency (y-axis) wrt color and fills based on "cut". I am good with this.

B) Now, in the second graph, I'm unsure what is happening:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(color, fill = cut)) +
geom_bar(position = "identity", alpha = 1 / 2, colour = "red")
```

Can someone please explain why the second graph is a little different (i.e. the height of bar graph is different in the two graphs; color scheme has also changed--I would have expected the bars to be red because I am explicitly setting colour = "red" but the bars have gradient color scheme, and they have a "red" border.

In drawing this, I am using publicly available `ggplot2` library and `diamond` dataset package that comes with it.

I am a beginner, so I am sorry if my question sounds too basic.

Comment: colour sets the colour of the border of the bar, not the fill of the bar

Comment: position= identity overlaps the bars, rather than stacking them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Richard Telford said, `position="identity"`overlaps the bar, and the default option is `position="stack"`as you can see with :

```
args(geom_bar)
function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "count", position = "stack", 
..., width = NULL, binwidth = NULL, na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, 
inherit.aes = TRUE)
```

`args` show the arguments for any function, with default values, as you can see here, the default value for `position` argument is "stack", so in your first exemple, bars are stacked.
And if you want to specify the "filling" colors, you need an special extra argument : a scale (if you try `fill=...` in the `geom_bar`call it overwrites `fill=cut` the the `ggplot`call). Here an exemple with ugly colors, and black borders :

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(color, fill = cut)) +
geom_bar(position = "stack", color="black") +
scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "gray70"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Toshiro and @Richard Telford : what's the difference between geom_bar(color = "red") vs. geom_point(color = "red")? I believe when I call geom_point (color = "red"), it fills the color. Isn't it? Hence, I would have expected the similar result when calling geom_bar(). I'm curious.

Comment: It depends ont wich "point" you use : the default point shape only has one color, some have a color and a fill option. Try this code with `pch=21`option to see the difference between color and fill.    `ggplot(data=data.frame(x=1:10, y=(1:10)^2), aes(x=x, y=y)) +
 geom_point(col="red", fill="yellow", pch=21, cex=5)`

Comment: Fantastic! How did you find out about pch and cex? I'm curious. I looked at ?geom_point, and didn't find it. I also tried `ggplot(data=data.frame(x=1:10, y=(1:10)^2), aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point(col="red", fill="yellow", pch=21, cex=5)` vs.  `ggplot(data=data.frame(x=1:10, y=(1:10)^2), aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point(col="red", fill="yellow")` and the two plots are significantly different.

Comment: Well, I've been too hurry : `pch=`and `cex=` are base `plot()` options, to be more precise, in `geom_point()` I should have written `shape=21`, which is more convenient with ggplot grammar (where shape can be a dynamic parameter). You can see the details (and different shapes) here : http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/shape. The difference between your graphs comes from the default shape (16) which only has one color (and default size `cex`).

Comment: nice tip: evoque alpha transparency to show overlaid bars as following: geom_bar(stat = "identity", position="identity" , alpha=0.5)